# What datatype should be chosen in sql server for storing C# enums?

Tags: sql-server, enums, sqldatatypes

Generally I choose int or tinyint for that but if I choose varchar it will be more clear while seeing data directly from the database table or while querying it.
But would it be the good practice to use varchar?
Or what is the good practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For indexing reasons a small numeric column would be better to use than a varchar, the size of which can only be determined by how many values are in the enumeration. If you require the text value to be returned from the database, store the text values in a separate lookup table and join when required.

Comment: Indeed, good suggestion. Here is a link that also explains why: http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on the kind of enum you want, basically for referencing value we use `int`.

Comment: +1 Indexing on `INT` field would perform better than `VARCHAR` field.